# Load 3D Model into Container dynamically via Dropwdown \ JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, model, 3d, rendering

Loading this model (example) here seems to nlt work the way I want.

I execute a JS and fill the "var" with an url

- that url is in the container to render the 3d model aswell...

Sadly the container-ed script will not take the new var at all it seems.

(if the url is present in script directly it worksy but I want to swap out the model dynamically

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #04AA6D;color: white;padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;
}
.dropdown {
position: relative;display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;position: absolute;background-color: #f1f1f1;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Model</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="javascript:var model = https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/banana.obj;">Model</a>
<a href="">Model2</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>


<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/OBJLoader.js'></script>
<script>
//This demo is using the plugin "OBJLoader". Don't forget to include it into your page ;)
//You can find it here : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/cf584a60bdfd24c42eaa81d484533364742bda44/examples/js/loaders
var renderer, scene, camera, banana;
var ww = window.innerWidth,
    wh = window.innerHeight;
function init(){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas : document.getElementById('scene')});
    renderer.setSize(ww,wh);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,ww/wh, 0.1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set(0,0,500);
    scene.add(camera);
    //Add a light in the scene
    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 350 );
    directionalLight.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    scene.add( directionalLight );
    //Load the obj file
    loadOBJ();
}
var loadOBJ = function(){
    //Manager from ThreeJs to track a loader and its status
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    //Loader for Obj from Three.js
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    //Launch loading of the obj file, addBananaInScene is the callback when it's ready 
    loader.load( '$model', addBananaInScene);
};
var addBananaInScene = function(object){
    banana = object;
    //Move the banana in the scene
    banana.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
    banana.position.y = -200;
    banana.position.z = 50;
    //Go through all children of the loaded object and search for a Mesh
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        //This allow us to check if the children is an instance of the Mesh constructor
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
            child.material.color = new THREE.Color(0X00FF00);
            //Sometimes there are some vertex normals missing in the .obj files, ThreeJs will compute them
            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        }
    });
    //Add the 3D object in the scene
    scene.add(banana);
    render();
};
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    //Turn the banana
    banana.rotation.z += .01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
init();
</script>
```

I tried to pass the url for the model via javascript

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: After selecting the js url from the dropdown: none. The script below does not react to it. The model is not rendered.

Comment: Someone with a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70823803/how-to-case-switch-between-models-in-three-js